# Showing triangulation inequality $E \le \frac{V(V-1)}{2}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show the simple inequality $E \le \frac{V(V-1)}{2}$ for any triangulation of a surface.

I've calculated that $E = \frac{3F}{2}$ for any triangulation and I know from the classification theorem of surfaces that $V-E+F \le 2$ but unfortunately that gives a lower bound on $E$ rather than an upper bound.

I want to somehow count the number of edges in terms of the vertices. I can see that whenever two triangles are identified each vertex of a triangulation is identified with at least one other and each edge corresponds to two vertices, but that only gives the inequality $E \le V^2 / 2$

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the triangulation; why would $E\leq{V\choose2}$?

Comment: Oh I see, frustrating I didn't notice that! Because given a set of $V$ vertices there are at most $\binom V 2$ ways to join them with edges. Some of them might not be joined! Thanks